# Open iOS app from facebook invite request

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-invite

So I'm trying to do what candy crush does and open my app immediately after the facebook request is tapped. Right now what's happening is the app store page for the app is opened instead of the already download app. How do I fix this?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add URL types to your app. Follow this guide (section 4) on official Facebook developer website - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/.

Afterwards, you can always open your app with the specific URL type (unique per app).

Answer (score 1):

you need to create your app on facebook and then integrated using url scheme. this is a turoral you need step 1-3 and step 
8
http://m-farhan.com/2014/03/ios-facebook-sdk-tutorial/

make sure you have setup facebook app